# boost::phoenix3 comma operator

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

What headers I should include to enable comma working as lambda expression?

```
( bind( f1 ), bind( f2 ), bind( f3 ) )() // calls f1, f2 and then f3
```

For boost::lambda it's a `<boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>`, but I didn't found single header in phoenix for such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should `#include <boost/spirit/home/phoenix/statement/sequence.hpp>`.

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/composite.html#phoenix.composite.statement.block_statement